# Обнаружение ошибки в файле XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Выводится ошибка: Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  CS1061  "MainWindow" не содержит определения "Window_Loaded", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Window_Loaded", принимающий тип "MainWindow" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).  WPF1    C:\Development\C#\WPF1\WPF1\MainWindow.xaml 8   Активные
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPF1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="350" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20 8 20 8" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            </Style>
                   
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="fructGrid">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Фрукты" Width="120"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Производитель" Width="125"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Цена за кг" Width="80"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
    
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="updateButton" Content="Обновить" Click="updateButton_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Content="Удалить" Click="deleteButton_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string connectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable fructTable;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        }
        private void Window_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM fruct";
            fructTable = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);   
                SqlCommand  command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);  
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("fruct_code", connection);
                adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50, "Title"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Company"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Price"));
                SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id"));

                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(fructTable);
                fructGrid.ItemsSource = fructTable.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();
            }

        }

        private void Update_DB()
        {
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Update(fructTable);
        }

        private void updateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Update_DB();
        }

        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fructGrid.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fructGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRowView dataRowView = fructGrid.SelectedItems[i] as DataRowView;
                    if (dataRowView != null)
                    {
                        DataRow dataRow = (DataRow)dataRowView.Row;
                        dataRow.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте перейти в «Сборка» ==> «Очистить решение» ==> «Выполнить» (f5)

Comment: или "Пересобрать"

Comment: скорее всего глюк, xaml вполне рабочий